# Gson to json returning empty map for a property

Tags: scala, gson

How can I get the json string that GSON makes to include the values within my map?

I have this case class

```
import com.google.gson.{Gson, GsonBuilder}


case class Example(SomeProperty: String, FruitMap: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])
```

And I need to convert it to JSON.

I am using new Gson(), like this:

```
val fruitMap = Map("fruit1" -> "apple", "fruit2" -> "banana", "fruit3" -> "orange")

val example1 = Example("prop1", fruitMap)
new Gson().toJson(example1)
```

However, the result is always empty:
`{"SomeProperty":"prop1","FruitMap":{}}`

Comment: With Scala 3 this seems to 'work', but you get something like `"FruitMap":{"scala$collection$immutable$Map$Map3$$key1":"fruit1",...` (and with Scala 2 `toJson(fruitMap)` also seems to produce such undesired output). If possible it might be easier if you switched to a JSON library with explicit Scala support.

Comment: Any reason not to use a JSON library that support Scala types? Jackson, play-json, Circe, zio-json... There are quite a few.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll be using instead Jackson.